# Basic user Entity Framework authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm writing a test web app in ASP.net core MVC and entity framework, I've built a login view and want to authenticate a user, with username and password against my users database table. This is for an in house app with max 10 users. I'm not using the Microsoft identity or user registrations. What would be the best way of approaching this basic user authentication?

Many thanks.

I'm getting an error with my **UserService** as it doesn't exist in the current context, and I'm getting an error with my **ClaimTypes** as it cannot convert from string to System.IO.BinaryReader

```
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser(string email)
        {
            var user = await UserService.GetUserByEmail(email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                TempData["Login failed"] = $"Login for {email} failed.";
                return this.Redirect("/Login");
            }

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name)
            };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(ClaimsIdentity));

        return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: bare asp.net core authentication without Identity, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply.

I've been testing with the cookies authorization and I just can't seem to get it to work. I'm quite new to all of this and I was wondering if you could perhaps point me to a step by step guide or something quite beginner friendly. 

Many thanks.

Comment: Elaborate on "can't seem to get it to work", are you getting errors? Post the code needed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've edited my original post with the code snippet I'm struggling with.

Comment: If you are not using Microsoft identity or user registrations, you need to write your own `UserService` and use it via dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks all, I managed to get it working by following a cookies authentication tutorial. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.